# Handling web service response with multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, web-services, multidimensional-array

I am consuming a web service which has multi dimensional array in response, i get undefined output when i alert the elements, please see the code below.

JSON RESPONSE

```
{  
   "status":1,
   "msg":"cc call history",
   "records":{  
      "1":{  
         "destination":"Canada - Fixed Others",
         "date":"May 05, 2010",
         "time_spent":"1 minutes",
         "amount_charged":"2.18"
      },
      "2":{  
         "destination":"Canada - Fixed Others",
         "date":"May 05, 2010",
         "time_spent":"1 minutes",
         "amount_charged":"2.18"
      }
   }
}
```

Javascript code

```
function call()
        {
            alert('call');
            var user_id = sessionStorage.getItem('user_id');
            var authentication_key = sessionStorage.getItem('auth_id');
            alert(user_id);
            alert(authentication_key);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://example.com/XXX',
                data: {user_id: user_id, authentication_key: authentication_key},
                success: function (response)
                {
                    obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    var status = obj.status;
                    var msg = obj.msg;
                    var records;

                    alert(status);
                    alert(msg);
                    alert(records);
                    if (status === '0')
                    {
                        alert(status);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var lnrc = obj.records.length;
                        alert(lnrc);
                        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                        {
                            alert('for');
                            var rc1 = obj.records[i];
                            alert(rc1);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function () {

                },
            });
        }
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: What multi dimensional array is being returned and where? Your questions says the API your consuming returns JSON? Can you explain further

Comment: `records` is an object, not an array..

Comment: What do you get if you use "console.log(response)" at the top of your success callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the for-in loop to iterate through `object`. Make sure that the key you get is an actual `property` of an `object`

```js
var obj = {
  "status": 1,
  "msg": "cc call history",
  "records": {
    "1": {
      "destination": "Canada - Fixed Others",
      "date": "May 05, 2010",
      "time_spent": "1 minutes",
      "amount_charged": "2.18"
    },
    "2": {
      "destination": "Canada - Fixed Others",
      "date": "May 05, 2010",
      "time_spent": "1 minutes",
      "amount_charged": "2.18"
    }
  }
};
var status = obj.status;
var msg = obj.msg;
var records;
if (status === '0') {
  alert(status);
} else {
  for (var key in obj.records) {
    if (obj.records.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(obj.records[key]);
    }
  }
  //OR
  Object.keys(obj.records).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(obj.records[key]);
  });
}
```

Comment: i get the output as [object,object] but where do i replace the key with my actual property

Comment: Like this: `console.log(obj.records[key]['destination']);`. `obj.records[key]` will return you object.